# Value stored to 'mySLComposerSheet' is never used

Tags: ios, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am having this issue with my code that I have tried hard to fix, but with no results. Here you can see the code I am talking about:

.m

```
    SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;

    mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Jeg har gennemført %i trænningspas med \"7 minutter\", som du kan hente her: http://bit.ly/7minutter", number]];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;
```

When I analyse the code, it gives me the following errors:

- Value stored in 'mySLComposerSheet' is never read
- Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

I really hope that one of you can help me by taking a quick look at my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the line:

`mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];`

`composeViewControllerForServiceType:` creates an instance of `SLComposeViewController`, thus the object returned by the `alloc init` is never used. See Apple's docs for more info:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Okay thanks! And now I have to write: _mySLComposerSheet where I previously just was writing mySLComposerSheet right?

Comment: Assuming you are using Xcode 4.4 or above, you don't need the`SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;` line in your `.m` file. And yes, just use `_ mySLComposerSheet`. It will be created for you automatically.

Comment: Mathias, if this answer worked for you, select the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Per my comment on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454754/xcode-potential-leak-of-an-object-stored-into-notification, use `self.mySLComposerSheet` instead of accessing the ivar directly.